# Изменить значение селектора на странице (C#)

Tags: c#, веб-программирование, restsharp

День добрый.
Я пытаюсь получить список пользователей с сайта (пусть это будет example.com\users) (используя RestSharp, но вообще лишь бы стало понятно наконец), а для этого нужно сначала вбить поисковые данные в селектор. Выглядит кусок кода страницы так:

```
<select name="search_users" id="search_users_id">
<option value="" selected="selected">Select a country</option>
<option value="1">Russia</option>
```

И несмотря на длительное чтение различных ресурсов, я всё еще не могу понять - как закинуть нужное значение "Russia" в качестве выбранного? Я понимаю, что надо отправить на сервер что-то вроде

```
<select name="search_users" id="search_users_id">
<option value="">Select a country</option>
<option value="1" selected="selected">Russia</option>
```

Но как это конкретно? Все, что я нахожу последнее время, это либо примеры "Как получить код страницы" (хотя как получить код страницы RestSharp'ом я тоже пока разбираюсь), либо что-то, что понятно уже прошаренным людям. Спасибо :)

Answer (score 0):

Дело не в restsharp'e, у вас отсутствует общее понимание веб-технологий.

Допустим, есть некоторая веб-страница, на которой отображается список пользователей какой-то страны в зависимости от выбранного фильтра:

```
<form method="post">

    <select name="country">
    <option value="">Select a country</option>
    <option value="1">Russia</option>
    <option value="2">USA</option>
    </select>

    .....
    <button type="submit">Filter</button>

</form>
```

То без разницы, используете ли вы браузер или restsharp -- всё равно на сервер не будет уходит вся эта портянка из select - option - option и так далее. На сервер передаётся переменная country и её значение, например 1 или 2.

Удобно это можно показать на страницах get-запросов. Например, если бы в этой форме был бы параметр method='get' - то браузер бы перешёл на страницу example.com\users?country=1 (в зависимости от того, что вы выбрали), ну если быть более точным - то на ту страницу, которая определена в action формы.

Таким образом примерный фрагмент через RestSharp будет вот такого вида:

```
var restClient = new RestClient("https://example.com");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.Resource = "/users";

request.AddParameter("search_users", 1);

// Тут могут быть ещё параметhы:
request.AddParameter("param", "value");

var response = restClient.Execute(request);
```